# Javascript copyText select option value showing value, but i need the description

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm busy with an html orderform, with steps. On the last step i'm making an summary. This is going well except for the category. Category value is filled by the database, and is the id from the category. But what i'm really need is the text in the option.

For example, category id = 62 with text: Huurwoning, now it is showing 62, but i want to show Huurwoning. This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H9McM/1/

```
<select name="catid" onmouseup="copyText(this)" id="catid" class="inputbox required"><option value="" >Selecteer Categorie&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="62" >Huurwoning</option><option value="58" >Kamerhuur</option><option value="59" >Parkeren</option><option value="60" >Vakantiewoning</option><option value="61" >Bedrijfsruimte</option></select>

<script>
function copyText(e)
 {
    var matchingElements = document.getElementsByClassName( e.name + 'preview' ),
        matchCount = matchingElements.length;

    for (var i =0; i< matchCount; i++){
       matchingElements[i].innerHTML = e.value;
    }
 } </script>

<script>
$(".catidpreview").draggable({ containment: '#dragcontainer' });
</script>

<div class="catidpreview"></div>
```

Comment: hi i have update you fiddle by e[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML;... try the link...http://jsfiddle.net/H9McM/4/

Comment: Thanks for updating, but when i'm put it into the script, it doesn't work :(. Could you take a look at this jsfiddle please? The select and input field both need to work. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/H9McM/9/

Comment: i have updated the fiddle and post the answer... try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the option text, you can try this:

```
matchingElements[i].innerHTML = e[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Also `onchange` might be a better event for this task.

A live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KfsJW/1/)

---

**EDIT**

Since you've complemented your question within a comment, here's the line you'll need within the `for` loop:

```
matchingElements[i].innerHTML = (e.type === 'text') ? e.value : e[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

A fixed demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KfsJW/3/)

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm for the category fields, but now my input fields not working anymore : http://jsfiddle.net/KfsJW/2/

Comment: There was no `input` nor `.titlepreview` field in your original question. `copyText()` is supposed to add `input` value into the `.titlepreview` too?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try the Below Codes....

**HTMLCode :**

```
<select name="catid" onmouseup="copyText(this)" id="catid" class="inputbox required"><option value="" >Selecteer Categorie&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="62" >Huurwoning</option><option value="58" >Kamerhuur</option><option value="59" >Parkeren</option><option value="60" >Vakantiewoning</option><option value="61" >Bedrijfsruimte</option></select>
<input name="title" onkeyup="copyText(this)" value="">

<div class="catidpreview"></div>
<div class="titlepreview"></div>
```

**JavaScript code**

```
function copyText(e)
 {

    var matchingElements = document.getElementsByClassName( e.name + 'preview' );
        matchCount = matchingElements.length;

  if(e.nodeName=="INPUT")
  {

    for (var i =0; i< matchCount; i++){
       matchingElements[i].innerHTML = e.value;;
    }
  }
     else
     {
    for (var i =0; i< matchCount; i++){
       matchingElements[i].innerHTML = e[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
     }
     }
} 



$(".catidpreview").draggable({ containment: '#dragcontainer' });
$(".titlepreview").draggable({ containment: '#dragcontainer' });
```

Updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/H9McM/10/